# Change Name of a .JSP file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, url, spring-mvc

I am developing a simple spring application. I have a few jsps and I would like to change the name and the URL of a jsp. I changed the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/simpleForm.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void simpleForm(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute(new User());
}
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newName.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void simpleForm(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute(new User());
}
```

and the name of the old `simpleForm.jsp` to `newName.jsp` `user` is a class I use in the form in `simpleform.jsp`

I couldn't make it work. I am getting 404 that simpleform.jsp is not found. I am pretty stuck.

Edit: My view resolver tags:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My url pattern is like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/forms/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

> I've found out that all of the links are getting the same error ()
>   resource not available. Even the ones that I didn't change the name
>   of.

I also tried directly starting from `newName.jsp`. Still the same error!

Comment: Are you getting simpleform.jsp not found or simpleForm.jsp not found?

Comment: I am getting () not found.But I was getting simpleForm.jsp not found.

Comment: What URL are you trying to access when you get that error?

Comment: By the way I am cofused with Model parameter in your function here. Why you define Model here. Is it modelAttribute?

    simpleForm(Model model)

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Be sure to 'accept' an answer that helped you!

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newName.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newName.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Thank you, but still a 404. But this time instead specific simpleForm.jsp couldn't found, it does not state which file is notfound: () resource not found.

Comment: type Status report |

message - |

description The requested resource () is not available.

Comment: try changing "/newName.jsp" to "newName.jsp" (without the slash)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/newName.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String simpleForm(Model model) {
           model.addAttribute(new User());
           return "newName";  // returning the desired view
    }
```

And make sure you have defined `viewResolver` accordingly like

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Change prefix as per your application structure.It will take the view (String returned by controller) and will add prefix and suffix. So the view resolved will be `/WEB-INF/jsp/newName.jsp`.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check you still have the `@Controller` annotation on the class. I've seen 404s when has been accidentally deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error is an HTTP status code that means that the page you were trying to reach on a website couldn't be found on their server.
As I can see, your suffix is .jsp. So try this (if there is any newName.jsp in the WebContent)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void simpleForm(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute(new User());
}
```

Comment: The same thing, still a 404. Where do I connect the view to the controller?

Comment: I think you are missing something. Is your newName.jsp in this directory? I mean is here: WEB-INF/views/newName.jsp ?

Answer (score 0):

It should work

If you try this URL

```
http://localhost:<port>/AppNAme/forms/newName.html
```

and your controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newName.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView simpleForm(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute(new User());

ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("jspViewName");
return mv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The forward slash is missing in the prefix of your ViewResolver. This should fix your 404. Give it a shot.

```
<property name="prefix">
<value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
</property>
```